# Specifiying a file in a specific directory in sed

Tags: sed

I'm using Sed on a Mac.  I am trying to do a simple string replace on a file that is not in the directory.  I do:

```
sed -i 's/old/new/' /Users/A/file
```

and it says invalid command code A.

What do I need to do?

Comment: If you try 
cat /Users/A/file | sed -i 's/old/new/' , do you have an error ?

Comment: is this `/Users/A/file` the fullpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-i` option in OSX/BSD `sed` is a little different than the GNU/Linux version in that it *requires* a backup extension to be given, even if it's an empty string (which means that no backup will be made). The "invalid command code" error message occurs because `s/old/new` is taken as the backup extension and `/Users/A/file` is taken as the script (where `A` is seen as an invalid command name). So it needs to be something like:

```
sed -i '' 's/old/new/' /Users/A/file
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have perl:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/old/new/' /Users/A/file
```

The `-i` in sed is not a standard across OS's (not a POSIX standard). This should work every time:

```
cp /Users/A/file /Users/A/file.sed
cat /Users/A/file.sed | sed 's/old/new' > /Users/A/file
```